# How to add time step dimension to generated batch by tf.data.Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.data.dataset

I want add time step dimension to my batch generation.

Currently I am doing

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.\
    from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).\
    shuffle(10000).\
    batch(32)
```

and getting batches of size `(32, feature_vector_length)`

I want to add time_step_dimention to my batch to have `(batch_size,time_stemp,feature_vector_length)`

How it can be dome using `tf.data` ?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is the `.window` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.window()` method of `tf.data.Dataset()` and `.zip()` your input and output.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

x_train = np.random.rand(1000, 5)
y_train = np.sum(x_train, axis=1)

x = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x_train).\
    window(size=3, shift=1, stride=1, drop_remainder=True).\
    flat_map(lambda l: l.batch(3))

y = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y_train)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip((x, y)).batch(2, drop_remainder=True)

for xx, yy in ds:
    print(xx, yy)
    break
```

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[0.85339111 0.00937855 0.6432005  0.31875691 0.83835893]
  [0.91914805 0.13469408 0.40381527 0.80296816 0.4389627 ]
  [0.40326491 0.28575999 0.86602507 0.40515333 0.35390637]]
 [[0.91914805 0.13469408 0.40381527 0.80296816 0.4389627 ]
  [0.40326491 0.28575999 0.86602507 0.40515333 0.35390637]
  [0.00197349 0.46558597 0.66426367 0.00787106 0.07879078]]], shape=(2, 3, 5), 
    dtype=float64) tf.Tensor([2.663086   2.69958826], shape=(2,), dtype=float64)
```

This is a batch of 2 tensors of 3 time steps of 5 features and their respective target.

Comment: Great example. I noticed, however, that the Y targets correspond to the first of the 3 X inputs in the window. In most cases you'll probably want them to be the targets for the last one instead. But that's easy to fix with y = y.skip(2) before the zip